# Ignore results less than X time apart

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

The data I currently have looks something like the table I have below:

```
 UserId      VisitDate
 1           2012-01-01 00:15:00.000
 1           2012-01-01 00:16:00.000
 1           2012-01-12 00:15:00.000
 1           2012-01-12 00:16:00.000
 1           2012-01-24 00:15:00.000
 1           2012-01-24 00:16:00.000
```

I would like to return only results than have been 10 or more days apart so that it looks like so:

```
 UserId      VisitDate
 1           2012-01-01 00:15:00.000
 1           2012-01-12 00:15:00.000
 1           2012-01-24 00:15:00.000
```

Simpler than I'm making it perhaps, but how would one go about doing so in transact-sql?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @SebastianMeine Whoops, added sql-server-2012 to the tags. Bet that helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the new `lag()` function in that case: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx

Something like:

```
SELECT UserId, VisitDate
FROM(
  SELECT UserId,
         VisitDate, 
         LAG(VisitDate,1,'1900-01-01')OVER(PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY VisitDate) PrevVisitDate
   FROM dbo.YourTable
)X
WHERE DATEDIFF(day,PrevVisitDate,VisitDate)>=10;
```

You can see it in action here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a0f02/1

Comment: Great! This looks like it will help. What is the `X` for?

Comment: If you use a subquery in after the `FROM` keyword you need to give it a name. I usually use an `X` there, even though it would be better to use a more descriptive name...

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Unfortunately here is what is returned with the results http://pastebin.mozilla.org/2135874 ; Each user has the same date and time?

Comment: It seems to work correctly for me. I added a SQLFiddle link to the answer. I also had to add a default value of 1900-01-01 for the `LAG` function, so the first row of each block would be included.

Comment: Works as expected. Thanks!